# Is there any option to use redis.expire more elastically?

Tags: redis

I got a quick simple question,

Assume that if server receives 10 messages from user within 10 minutes, server sends a push email.

At first I thought it very simple using redis,

```
incr("foo"), expire("foo",60*10)
```

and in Java, handle the occurrence count like below

```
if(jedis.get("foo")>=10){sendEmail();jedis.del("foo");}
```

but imagine if user send one message at first minute and send 8 messages at 10th minute.

and the key expires, and user again send 3 messages in the next minute.

redis key will be created again with value 3 which will not trigger sendEmail() even though user send 11 messages in 2 minutes actually.

we're gonna use Redis and we don't want to put receive time values to redis.

is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's 2 ways of solving this-- one to optimize on space and the other to optimize on speed (though really the speed difference should be marginal).

**Optimizing for Space:**

Keep up to 9 different counters; `foo1 ... foo9`. Basically, we'll keep one counter for each of the possible up to 9 different messages before we email the user, and let each one expire as it hits the 10 minute mark. This will work like a circular queue. Now do this (in Python for simplicity, assuming we have a connection to Redis called `r`):

```
new_created = False
for i in xrange(1,10):
    var_name = 'foo%d' % i
    if not (new_created or r.exists(var_name)):
        r.set(var_name, 0)
        r.expire(var_name, 600)
        new_created = True
    if not r.exists(var_name): continue
    r.incr(var_name, 1)
    if r.get(var_name) >= 10: 
        send_email(user)
        r.del(var_name)
```

If you go with this approach, put the above logic in a Lua script instead of the example Python, and it should be quite fast. Since you'll at most be storing 9 counters per user, it'll also be quite space efficient.

**Optimizing for speed:**

Keep one Redis Sortet Set per user. Every time a user sends a message, add to his sorted set with a key equal to the timestamp and an arbitrary value. Then just do a `ZCOUNT(now, now - 10 minutes)` and send an email if that's greater than 10. Then `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE(now - 10 minutes, inf)`. I know you said you didn't want to keep timestamps in Redis, but IMO this is a better solution, and you're going to have to hold some variant on timestamps somewhere no matter what.

Personally I'd go with the latter approach because the space differences are probably not that big, and the code can be done quickly in pure Redis, but up to you.

Comment: One thing I didn't mentioned is that the time interval varies for every user so I think second option might be a better way, I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @이승진 yeah, I assumed that. For the first method, the idea is you just have a foo1...9 per user. Just append user_id to each one, or anything along those lines. Anyway, I agree the second approach is better. Let me know how it goes.